# Images in HipChat

Tags: hipchat

If I sent an image to someone in HipChat, would it be stored on my computer somewhere? Can I find it?

I've already looked in my pictures and stuff, it's not there, and I don't have access to the HipChat server anymore.

Answer (score 1):

HipChat usually stores all content send on an Amazon Web Services's cloud instance used with the provider. To find the content you sent to someone, select the person in the people list and on the left there will be a panel listing all the files ever shared with that person. Click on the file name and it will either preview it for you or offer to download. See the attached image for illustration [image: Hipchat window with "Files" panel]